# Set Case Status Button component on Customer Community Napili Template

Tags: community, lightning, customer-community, napili

I'm not able to see the "Set Case Status Button component" on Napili lightning Template. Salesforce documentation http://resources.docs.salesforce.com/200/19/en-us/sfdc/pdf/community_templates.pdf page No 171 illustrates about this feature, but I couldn't see this component on list of available lightning components on Napili. Appreciate any help in this

Comment: Are you on Spring 16 template of Napili ?